# Relation between Cold & Mood

Tags: brain, common-cold, mood-moodiness

Every single time whenever symptoms of a cold start to develop, excluding the general irritation (headaches, runny nose, etc) - there are moments where my mood just gets extremely positive. Is there any relation between colds and some sort of happy high?

It's very strange that such good feeling onsets during colds.

Comment: For record, I feel the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Reflexively I want to say it's due to the medicine -- commonly "Sudafed" which contains "Pseudoephedrine" or "Phenylephrine".   The former can be used to manufacture  methamphetamines (also known as meth).

Oddly enough I've experienced the same thing, a good mood and very noticeable feeling of relaxation. I can't help but think there is something more going on here (from a physiological standpoint, as I don't always take "Sudafed" when I have a cold).  **I'd be very interested hear what other knowledgeable members have to say regarding this.**

+1 - Fantastic question by the way..

Comment: Indeed, even without any medicine said feeling still ensues. I would add "nostalgic" to describe the feeling, but that contains sad/negative nuances and probably just remembering past happy-high-colds. Strangely enough, it's one of the best moods.

Comment: Perhaps on prior use of pseudoephedrine (which as you are aware, works not unlike amphetamine) your mind has correlated pseudo use with having a cold, and through association, you experience a slight mood elevation? Colds typically have a detrimental effect on hedonic capacity, alertness, and psychomotor speed (according to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22749892 and  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9854744)